# Inserting Data from 1 CTE into another CTE within the time limits

Tags: sql-server

So i have A CTE that creates the results below.This is an example of a batch run and the phases that batch went through and their respective start and end times. What i want to accomplish is take the data gathered during that batch run and insert between the phases during which the time the data came into my table.

```
rownum PhaseName  PhaseID      Time                    TimeEnd

 1      Air Removal          2  2016-06-01 11:46:46.000   2016-06-01 11:56:47.000

 2      Heat up                 3  2016-06-01 11:56:47.000   2016-06-01 12:06:17.000

 3      Steriliztion         4  2016-06-01 12:06:17.000   2016-06-01 12:23:40.000

 4      Air Pressurization   5  2016-06-01 12:23:40.000   2016-06-01 12:27:18.000

 5      Exhaust              6  2016-06-01 12:27:18.000   2016-06-01 12:29:35.000 

 6      Drying               7  2016-06-01 12:29:35.000   2016-06-01 12:34:36.000

 7      Equalization         8  2016-06-01 12:34:36.000   2016-06-01 12:34:36.000
```

Lets assume a datapoint came in with the data:

```
Chamber Pressure 2016-06-03 11:47:23.000 
Chamber Temperature 2016-06-03 12:10:24.000
```

I want to place that data under the phase it was collected under. So the first datapoint is under Air Removal, the second one is under Sterilization.

The reason for this is, I would like to use the Phase Name as the Parent group in my SSRS. However my code right now tend to create holes and the full join creates a lot of unwanted data which i have fought using filters in the SSRS.

CODE:

```
;with ss (EquipmentTag, Name) as(
            Select        'Equipment Tags_IO_RedirectAI_udt{0}_Out_real', '(PIT112) Chamber Pressure' Union
            Select        'Equipment Tags_IO_RedirectAI_udt{1}_Out_real','(TT113) Drain Temperaure' Union
            Select        'Equipment Tags_IO_RedirectAI_udt{2}_Out_real','(TT205) Jacket Temperature' Union
            Select        'Equipment Tags_IO_RedirectAI_udt{3}_Out_real','(TT114) Filter Temperature' Union
            Select        'Equipment Tags_IO_RedirectAI_udt{4}_Out_real','(TT405) Waste Water Temperature' Union
            Select        'Equipment Tags_IO_RedirectAI_udt{7}_Out_real','(TT401) Vacuum Pump Seal Water Temperature' Union
            Select        'Equipment Tags_IO_RedirectAI_udt{8}_Out_real','(TT115.1) Chamber Temperaure' Union
            Select        'Equipment Tags_PID{0}_Output','Chamber Temperature PID Output' Union
            Select        'Equipment Tags_PID{1}_Output','Drain Temperature PID Output' Union
            Select        'Equipment Tags_PID{2}_Output','Filter Temperature PID Output' Union
            Select        'Equipment Tags_PID{3}_Output','Jacket Temperature PID Output' Union
            Select        'Equipment Tags_PID{4}_Output','Jacket Cooling Water PID Output' Union
            Select        'Equipment Tags_PID{0}_Setpoint','Chamber Temperature PID Setpoint' Union
            Select        'Equipment Tags_PID{1}_Setpoint','Drain Temperature PID Setpoint' Union
            Select        'Equipment Tags_PID{2}_Setpoint','Filter Temperature PID Setpoint' Union
            Select        'Equipment Tags_PID{3}_Setpoint','Jacket Temperature PID Setpoint' Union
            Select        'Equipment Tags_PID{4}_Setpoint','Jacket Cooling Water PID Setpoint' Union
            Select        'PID_Chamber_PIC_CtrlParamsBackUp_Gain','Chamber Temperature PID Proportional Gain' Union
            Select        'PID_Chamber_PIC_CtrlParamsBackUp_Td','Chamber Temperature PID Differential Gain' Union
            Select        'PID_Chamber_PIC_CtrlParamsBackUp_Ti','Chamber Temperature PID Integral Gain' Union
            Select        'PID_Drain_TIC_CtrlParamsBackUp_Gain','Drain Temperature PID Proportional Gain' Union
            Select        'PID_Drain_TIC_CtrlParamsBackUp_Td','Drain Temperature PID Differential Gain' Union
            Select        'PID_Drain_TIC_CtrlParamsBackUp_Ti','Drain Temperature PID Integral Gain' Union
            Select        'PID_Filter_TIC_CtrlParamsBackUp_Gain','Filter Temperature PID Proportional Gain' Union
            Select        'PID_Filter_TIC_CtrlParamsBackUp_Td','Filter Temperature PID Differential Gain' Union
            Select        'PID_Filter_TIC_CtrlParamsBackUp_Ti','Filter Temperature PID Integral Gain' Union
            Select        'PID_Jacket_TIC_CtrlParamsBackUp_Gain','Jacket Temperature PID Proportional Gain' Union
            Select        'PID_Jacket_TIC_CtrlParamsBackUp_Td','Jacket Temperature PID Differential Gain' Union
            Select        'PID_Jacket_TIC_CtrlParamsBackUp_Ti','Jacket Temperature PID Integral Gain' Union
            Select        'PID_Jacket_Cooling_Water_CtrlParamsBackUp_Gain','Jacket Temperature PID Proportional Gain' Union
            Select        'PID_Jacket_Cooling_Water_CtrlParamsBackUp_Gain','Jacket Cooling Water Temperature PID Proportional Gain' Union
            Select        'PID_Jacket_Cooling_Water_CtrlParamsBackUp_Td','Jacket Cooling Water Temperature PID Differential Gain' Union
            Select        'PID_Jacket_Cooling_Water_CtrlParamsBackUp_Ti','Jacket Cooling Water Temperature PID Integral Gain' union
            Select        'Controller Tags_PhaseID' , 'PhaseID'),

    ss3(pkid,PhaseName) as(select 0, '' union
           select '1', 'Setup' union
           select '2', 'Air Removal' union
           select '3', 'Heat up' union
           select '4', 'Sterilization' union
           select '5', 'Air Pressurization' union
           select '6', 'Exhaust' union
           select '7', 'Drying' union
           select '8', 'Equalization' union
           select '17', 'Air Pressure Test' union
           select '18', 'Filter Sterilization' union
           select '19', 'Air Leak Test'),
    ss2 as (
    select a.Name, Cast(TimeString as DateTime) as Time, cast(VarValue as float) as Value from Datalog0 as e left join ss as a on
    e.VarName = a.Name where a.Name <> 'PhaseID'--)
    union all
    select PhaseName,Cast(TimeString as DateTime) as Time, cast(b.VarValue as float) as Value 
    from ss3 d inner join SiemensArchive b on b.VarValue = d.pkid where b.VarName = 'PhaseActive'),

    ss4 as ( Select i.Name,i.Time, i.Value, PhaseName from ss2 i full join ss3 j on cast(j.pkid as decimal) = i.value),
    ss6 as(select distinct row_number() over(order by value asc) as rownum, PhaseName, value as PhaseID,
        Time from ss4 where PhaseName <> '' and value <> 0),

    ss7 as(select i.rownum,i.PhaseName,i.PhaseID, i.time as TimeStart, lead(i.time) over(order by Time) as TimeEnd  from ss6 as i)
    --select * from ss7
    select distinct coalesce(a.PhaseName,'Charge Gasket') as Phase,a.TimeStart,
     A.Timeend,  b.Name,b.Value,b.time from ss7 a full join ss2 b on a.Timestart <= b.Time and a.timeend >= b.time
     and b.name <> 'Air Removal' and b.name <> 'Heat Up' and b.Name <> 'Sterilization' and b.name <> 'Filter Sterilization' 
     and b.name <> 'Air Pressurization' and b.name <> 'Equalization' and b.name <> 'Charge Gasket' 
     and a.PhaseName <> b.Name and b.Name <> 'Exhaust' and b.Name <> 'Drying'
     group by timestart,phasename,timeend,name,value,time
     order by timestart,time,timeend
```

DataLog0:

```
   Equipment Tags_PID_CV_real{1}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   6/1/2016 11:56:28          100                    1        42522497543.4375
Equipment Tags_PID_CV_real{2}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   6/1/2016 11:56:28          0                      1        42522497543.4375
Equipment Tags_PID_CV_real{4}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   6/1/2016 11:56:28          0                      1        42522497543.4375
Equipment Tags_PID_CV_real{3}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   6/1/2016 11:56:28          0                      1        42522497543.4375
Equipment Tags_PID{0}_SetPoint                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  6/1/2016 11:56:28          29                     1        42522497543.4375
PhaseActive                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     6/1/2016 11:56:47          3                      1        42522497763.5069
Equipment Tags_IO_RedirectAI_udt{0}_Out_real                                                                                                                                                                                                                    6/1/2016 11:57:28          23.3567390441895       1        42522498237.9282
Equipment Tags_IO_RedirectAI_udt{8}_Out_real                                                                                                                                                                                                                    6/1/2016 11:57:28          112.375122070313       1        42522498237.9282
Equipment Tags_PID{1}_SetPoint                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  6/1/2016 11:57:28          121.099998474121       1        42522498237.9282
Equipment Tags_PID{2}_SetPoint                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  6/1/2016 11:57:28          122.5                  1        42522498237.9282
Equipment Tags_PID{4}_SetPoint                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  6/1/2016 11:57:28          0                      1        42522498237.9282
Equipment Tags_PID{3}_SetPoint                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  6/1/2016 11:57:28          119.800003051758       1        42522498237.9282
Equipment Tags_IO_RedirectAI_udt{3}_Out_real                                                                                                                                                                                                                    6/1/2016 11:57:28          26.4351387023926       1        42522498237.9282
Equipment Tags_IO_RedirectAI_udt{2}_Out_real                                                                                                                                                                                                                    6/1/2016 11:57:28          120.220428466797       1        42522498237.9282
Equipment Tags_IO_RedirectAI_udt{4}_Out_real                                                                                                                                                                                                                    6/1/2016 11:57:28          57.4743041992188       1        42522498237.9282
Equipment Tags_IO_RedirectAI_udt{7}_Out_real                                                                                                                                                                                                                    6/1/2016 11:57:28          31.2780513763428       1        42522498237.9282
Equipment Tags_IO_RedirectAI_udt{1}_Out_real                                                                                                                                                                                                                    6/1/2016 11:57:28          111.593315124512       1        42522498237.9282
Equipment Tags_PID_CV_real{0}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   6/1/2016 11:57:28          31.2675533294678       1        42522498237.9282
Equipment Tags_PID_CV_real{1}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   6/1/2016 11:57:28          30.1672401428223       1        42522498237.9282
Equipment Tags_PID_CV_real{2}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   6/1/2016 11:57:28          0                      1        42522498237.9282
Equipment Tags_PID_CV_real{4}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   6/1/2016 11:57:28          0                      1        42522498237.9282
Equipment Tags_PID_CV_real{3}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   6/1/2016 11:57:28          0                      1        42522498237.9282
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** solution:

```
WITH FirstCTE
AS (   
    SELECT PhaseName, PhaseId, TimeStart FROM ... 
), SecondCTE
AS (   
    SELECT PhaseName, PhaseId, TimeStart FROM ... 
), AllResults
AS (
    SELECT * FROM FirstCTE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM SecondCTE
) 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.TimeStart) AS RowNum, *, LEAD(a.TimeStart) OVER(ORDER BY a.TimeStart) AS TimeEnd
FROM AllResults a
ORDER BY RowNum
```

Comment: How would i bring the other data into the temptable? right now my results have another column that show what phase the data is coming from and as long it is within the timestart and timeend of that phase, the name of the phase will be in the column.

Comment: @aliaslam: see updated solution. It assumes that all CTEs are part of the same statement.